How to fix DLL error in Image classification problem in CNN?
open Anaconda prompt
conda create -n myenv
conda create -n automated_class python=3.7.10
activate automated_class
pip install matplotlib
conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
pip install trackpy
pip install opencv-python
pip install sklearn
pip install scikit-image
pip install jupyter
pip install spyder
pip install -U scikit-learn
pip3 install datasets
I HAVE created this environment for CNN work for image classification. this is installation problem. I have done all step but I am getting
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8272\2023103085.py in 
1 import torch
2 import torch.nn as nn
----> 3 import torchvision
4 from torchvision import datasets, transforms, models
5 import time
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\automated_class_2\lib\site-packages\torchvision_init_.py in 
5
6 from torchvision import models
----> 7 from torchvision import datasets
8 from torchvision import ops
9 from torchvision import transforms
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\automated_class_2\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets_init_.py in 
----> 1 from .lsun import LSUN, LSUNClass
2 from .folder import ImageFolder, DatasetFolder
3 from .coco import CocoCaptions, CocoDetection
4 from .cifar import CIFAR10, CIFAR100
5 from .stl10 import STL10
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\automated_class_2\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\lsun.py in 
1 from .vision import VisionDataset
----> 2 from PIL import Image
3 import os
4 import os.path
5 import io
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\automated_class_2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in 
98     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
99     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
--> 100     from . import _imaging as core
101
102     if version != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
this error always. what should I do ? i am struggling with this issue.
I tried several way to solve this issue. Install and reinstall all libraries. I do not know what should I do ?
